# Jenkins shows different time for the same builds in Stage View & Build History

Tags: jenkins

I run Jenkins as a standalone build machine.

It works fine, I have already created multiple pipelines.
But it displays two different time for the same builds in Stage View and Build history.
The difference between the time is exactly 2 hours.

Look at the attached screenshot for more demonstrative illustration of the problem.

How I can fix this?

[image]

Comment: Are you in GMT+/-2 time zone? :-)

Comment: if your trying to use the latest version of jenkins, you should get used to this place :https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/secure/Dashboard.jspa

Comment: @StephenKing yes. I'm in GMT +2 timezone :)

Comment: @Cole9350 do you think this may be an issue of the latest Jenkins version?

Answer (score 5):

Looks like the build time under build history is getting picked from Jenkins server time and the stage view time is your system's local time. Looks like a bug to me.

Temporary fix can be to match your timezone.
On Jenkins script console https://jenkins-servername/script
Run

```
System.setProperty('org.apache.commons.jelly.tags.fmt.timeZone', 'America/New_York')
```

Set it to match your timezone. [Read](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Change+time+zone)

Comment: Agree. Will try to math time on server to my local timezone

Comment: A workaround (?) if you have all your jenkins users in one location. But how does this work when you have multiple users in different timezones?

This seems like a bug in stage view to me

Comment: @Sentient I have clearly mentioned a temporary fix, I do not see a reason for a negative vote here.

Comment: would that not only work when all your users have the America/New_York timezone?

Comment: This is indeed a bug to me. If my entire Jenkins environment is UTC, why the Stage View is not? Setting up specific timezones per user will cause confusion in conversations since we have people all around the world.

Answer (score 2):

Had the same problem today. I solved it by changing the 'User Defined Time Zone'.

Current User > Configuration > User Defined Time Zone > Select correct time zone

The problem comes when the time zone configured in the user profile differs from de one configured in the cron of the pipeline.